# string match - find all occurrences of the same word in the string being evaluated

Tags: c#

Looking to find a way, via string match, to find multiple occurrences of the same word using the streamreader class and contains method (or some other approach).  Below only returns a match on the first occurrence, however if I'm evaluating a string that has "the" 3 times in the string, how can I capture all 3 of those for a count result?

```
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)    
{
      if (line.Contains(text))
      {
          counter++;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex.Matches(line, text).Count
```

Comment: for the exercise looking for a way to do a string match comparison.